# I've been trying to use a multi dimensional array to create the layout of a movie theater. Using an X for closed and O for open

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

```
          String[,] arr1 = new String[10,10];

          arr1[0,1] = "o " + "o";  
          arr1[1,1] = "o " + "o";
          arr1[2,1] = "x " + "o";
          arr1[3,1] = "o " + "o";
          arr1[4,1] = "x " + "o";
          arr1[5,1] = "o " + "o";
          arr1[6,1] = "o " + "o";
          arr1[7,1] = "o " + "o";
          arr1[8,1] = "o " + "o";
          arr1[9,1] = "o " + "o";
```

So this is the code ive used to populate the different indexes however the problem is that it fills in only an O,O (or X,O) instead of going through 10 times like in an actual theater like this: OOOXOOXO. I then need to allow the user to select a seat using the index of the array to check if its available. Any ideas?? 
[The General idea of how i need to format the output refer to the Martineau Hall](http://www.dorkinghalls.co.uk/index.cfm?articleid=26653)

Comment: Just as a side note, i cant just add extra O/Xs in the " " as then when i try to check if the seat is available itll run through the entire index entry and see that theres Os and Xs in the 1 index

Comment: Please provide a good description and samples of what you want the code to do and what the output should be.

Comment: I need it to output in Rows and Columns like when you book online for a movie, itll show an image of the theater with which seats are taken and available. Im trying to use an array for the column and rows then an X for if the seat is taken and an O for if its open

Comment: You're only setting the first column by specifying 1 as the second index. Why were you expecting this to set the whole array?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize it with literals, without any loop etc., go with something like

```
String[,] arr1 = new String[10, 10]
{
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
    { "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o ", "o", "o", "o" },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *jagged array* `string[][]` instead of *2D* one `string[,]`:

1. Jagged arrays are more *flexible*: what if some rows have *different* number of seats than others?
2. Jagged arrays are *easier to operate with*: *Linq*

Let's create movie theatre:

```
 // Empty 
 String[][] arr1 = Enumerable
   .Range(1, 10)               // ten rows 
   .Select(rank => Enumerable  // each row has
      .Range(1, 10)            // ten 
      .Select(file => "o")     // free seats (o)
      .ToArray())              // organized in array
   .ToArray();

 // Some seats are taken
 arr1[2][1] = "x";
 arr1[4][1] = "x";

 // Let's print out the map
 Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr1
   .Select(rank => string.Concat(rank))));
```

Outcome:

```
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oxoooooooo
oooooooooo
oxoooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
oooooooooo
```

Comment: This is a very good answer! 
I just hope that the OP understands Linq and lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Since your array seems to only store a single letter. Changing it from `string[,]` to `char[,]` would prevent you from having more than a single letter.

In case you only need the seats to be free or not free i would recommend using a `bool[,]` instead.

I will keep the `string[,]` as my answer since that is what you used in your question.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[,] arr1 = NewTheater();

        arr1[2, 1] = "x";
        arr1[4, 1] = "x";

    }

    private static string[,] NewTheater()
    {
        string[,] theater = new string[10, 10];

        for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
        {
            for (int seat = 0; seat < 10; seat++)
            {
                theater[row, seat] = "o";
            }
        }
        return theater;
    }
```